# CSS Styling the background color of specific table columns NOT nth-child

Tags: css

I realize this has been asked a million times before but I can't seem to locate a solution for what I'm seeking and I'm wondering if perhaps it just can't be done.

*The following uses doctype strict:*

I have a TABLE with a total of eight columns.
Column 1 is populated by links.
Columns 2-8 are days of the week beginning with Monday, thus:

LINKS | Monday | **Tuesday** | Wednesday | **Thursday** | Friday | **Saturday** | Sunday

Using primary colors for quick identification:

- Column 3 (Tue) should have a background color: BLUE
- Columns 5 (Thurs)    and 7 (Sat) should have a background color: GREEN

Is there a way to define the two column background-color styles in CSS **globally** such that no further coding outside of the CSS is needed? ie. ***every*** table uses these same two column styles, and no other reference within the individual `<TABLE>` tags themselves is necessary no matter how many additional tables are added to the page? I can post some code when I understand even a basic approach as to how/if this can be accomplished (including the `<thead>` and `<td>` etc. tags). Thank you.

#### Please see the latest REVISION [HERE](http://www.cssdesk.com/eDGVZ)

Answer (score 1):

Just type the following lines in a separate css and add it to your html

```
td:nth-child(3) { background-color: blue; }
td:nth-child(5),td:nth-child(7) { background-color: green; }
```

3,5 and 7 are column numbers

if you want to give a separate colour for table heading row use

```
thead{ background-color:purple; }
```

(turns table header background color into purple.) if you used thead tags in your html otherwise you can get same result by using

```
tr:nth-child(1) {background-color: purple;}
```

Comment: RD . . . I'm obviously not an expert at this so may I ask: I always thought nth-child related to rows (not columns) and had binary characteristics (this row white, this row yellow, this row white, this row yell~ etc.)

Comment: nth-child can apply not just to rows. It can apply to columns too.

Comment: semicodin..I can't get the meaning of your 2nd comment.But Let me explain the statement made by me.Normally css codings are separated from html when doing web pages.So if you do that then you have to link that css in your html.That way is pretty neat actually.

Comment: You can embed it in your html too. But then you can't reuse that code in another html

Comment: Here is a sample for my answer made by me. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xy0qCnAYeqDFB5GC9RVGEVjUVmti6uD2

Comment: RD . . . thank you for your patience. I've deleted my rants (late here, tired). But this exercise was important in that I located a free online site that I can upload my projects to.  I've added my first revision; please ►see the bottom of my lead post. I'll get better at this, but for now it gets the ball rolling!

Comment: You can do it pal.Take a rest and start again.I think https://www.w3schools.com/ is a good reference site for you to learn web technologies. You can get good on this after doing excercises in there

Comment: correction:code must be td:nth-child(3) {background-color: blue;}
td:nth-child(5),td:nth-child(7) {background-color: green;}

Comment: RD, everything looking good, however the purple header background spills onto the row following it so I will experiment a bit and report back. Thanks again RD.